# AngularJS set up with Webstorm

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I'm getting started with Angularjs and fallen at the first hurdle :-(

i've installed node (windows installer) and the webstorm ide. in webstorm i've installed the angularjs plugin and in the html typing 'ng' prompts all the ng templates in a dropdown, so this look ok.

cutting and pasting in the demo html5 (under the heading 'The Basics' at http://angularjs.org/) and running in webstorm and navigating to the file url (in firefox or chrome) however the angular statement '{{yourName}}' isn't binding at all - it's rendered out as a literal. Anyone know where i'm going wrong ?

Comment: It looks like AngularJS didn't get initialized. Are you sure that you've added `ng-app` like in the example? Is the AngularJS code properly downloaded and no errors showing up in the console?

Comment: yes, 'ng-app' is included. i do have an error in the console, so you may be onto something there. it states "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared" In schemas and dtds in webstorm i have encoding set to html5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example on the home page was using protocol-less (or protocol-relative) URLs (http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). While those are very handy, protocol-relative URLs don't play nicely with the `file://` protocol in this case. Simply your  browser is trying to retrieve AngularJS library from the local file system. To fix it you need to add protocol:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Opened a pull request for this issue as well: https://github.com/angular/angularjs.org/pull/29

Comment: Protocol can be missing, it uses the currently in use protocol. It's really nice when you don't have to check which version of your resource to load. It just loads the SSL version if the page is currently using https or not if it's http. No bug here.

Comment: But if you're not running files through a web server but straight from the filesystem it will not work because it wil try to load the resources with file:// protocol.

Comment: yes. i am also having same problem with angular.js file. In webstorm i have to add complete path "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js". Instead of this i want to use the local system path where i downloaded angular.js. How can i configure angular.js path with webstorm?

Answer (score 0):

Try prefixing the ng tag with data like data-ng-model.